# Like hdparm, how to calculate disk speed from fio command

Tags: linux, io

Using Hdparm, I will get disk speed value directly using following command:

```
hdparm -t test_filesystem | awk 'NF'
```

Likewise, please let me know how to calculate disk speed of any device from fio command output.

I am using below fio command,

```
fio --name=job1 --rw=read --size=1g --output-format=json --directory=test_directory
```

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: ensure your disk does not have partitions or filesystems or data that you want to keep on it!

To be closer to hdparm you will:

- Want to use http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-filename and use the name of the disk (e.g. `filename=/dev/sdj` ) rather than `directory=`.
- Want to use an I/O engine (http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-ioengine ) that can submit asynchronously (e.g. `ioengine=libaio`)
- Want to use options such as http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-direct that submit I/O in a way that bypasses your OS' cache (e.g. `direct=1`)

In bash you can use a tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract the "bw" key from the JSON output and note the parameter is nested within `jobs -> [<direction e.g. "read">]`